# I save only the last username on txt file instead the whole list

Tags: php, foreach

The following code prints on screen a list of usernames. However on the fid.txt file, only the last one username is saved. What am I missing here?

```
foreach ($twitter_xml->channel->item as $key) {
$author = $key->guid;

preg_match("#http://twitter.com/([^\/]+)/statuses/.*#", $author, $matches);

print_r($matches[1]);

file_put_contents('fid.txt', $matches[1]);
}
```

Comment: You need to set the FILE_APPEND flag (see [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`file_put_contents` overwrites the file by default. Change it to use append mode, and it'll probably do what you expect.

```
file_put_contents('fid.txt', "\n" . $matches[1], FILE_APPEND); // also added a newline to break things up
```

Even better, you should append to the string, and only write to the file once:

```
$usernames = array();
foreach ($twitter_xml->channel->item as $key) {
    // ... stuff ...
    $usernames[] = $matches[1];
}
// Save everything, separated by newlines
file_put_contents('fid.txt', "\n" . implode("\n", $usernames), FILE_APPEND);
```

Answer (score 3):

Unless you use the `FILE_APPEND` flag, `file_put_contents()` will open, write to, and close the file anew each time.

Try `file_put_contents('fid.txt', $matches[1], FILE_APPEND);`

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `file_put_contents('fid.txt', $matches[1], FILE_APPEND);`

By default `file_put_contents()` overwrites the file each call.

Answer (score 2):

`file_put_contents('fid.txt', $matches[1], FILE_APPEND);`

You are overwriting the whole file each time.